# How do you map a function to only certain elements in a list?

Tags: list, dictionary, if-statement, functional-programming, ocaml

E.g. if you have a function `(fun x -> x+1)` and you want to map it to `[1; 2; 3]`. But you only want to map it when `x=1`, so that the output is `[2; 2; 3]`. How do you do this?

Using OCaml, I tried:

```
let rec foo (input : int list) : int list =
match input with
    | [] -> []
    | hd::tl -> List.map (fun x -> if x=1 then (x+1)) input;;
```

And I've tried 'when' statements, but to no avail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `else` branch is missing here.

You're almost there. You just need to make a complete if/else statement:

`if x=1 then (x+1) else x`

OCaml requires a return value on any branch of above expression.

To be clear, `when` guard is irrelevant here because it is used for conditional pattern matching. Since pattern matching is redundant in this case, your function could be shortened quite a lot:

```
let foo input =
    List.map (fun x -> if x=1 then x+1 else x) input
```

Comment: I feel like I tried that but it didn't work -- But it worked just now. Rockstar, you.

Thanks for the tip on 'when'.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use a `when` statement, even if I prefer @pad's solution:

```
let foo (input : int list) : int list = 
  let rec aux acc input = 
   match input with
      [] -> List.rev acc
    | x :: xs when x = 1 -> aux ((x + 1) :: acc) xs
    | x :: xs -> aux (x :: acc) xs
  in
  aux [] input
```

Comment: And this one is tail-recursive ;-)

Comment: Yes, it is tail recursive, but I prefer the solution with List.map :-)